# Vertical Scrolling Hack, Horizontal Scroll Content

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

This question was asked, and I am trying to do something similar, since I posted there trying to ask for alternatives but the comment was deleted I am asking a new question.

This version of the answer Removes the natural Horizontal feature, and istead of replace horizontal with vertical, I want to add it as an additional feature, as when you horizontal scroll it horizontally scrolls, but when you vertical scroll is horizontally scrolls. So you can do either or, and it has the same effect..

Here is the example code.

Can you help make both functions availible to Horizontal scroll, when either moving mousewheel up or down or using a track pad to scroll up or down, or by moving the scroll bars vertically.. The end result is to scroll content horizontal regardless.

[Hacking Vertical Scroll into Horizontal Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885059/hacking-vertical-scroll-into-horizontal-scroll)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Scrolling test</title>
<!-- jQuery library - I get it from Google API's -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var leftScroll = $(window).scrollLeft();
    $(window).scrollLeft(topScroll);
    $("body").css("padding-top", leftScroll);
});

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-Serif;
    font-size: 46px;
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

body {
    height: 1000px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tincidunt dictum rhoncus. Phasellus nulla nulla, facilisis eu aliquam aliquet, mattis pulvinar purus. </h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to make the code better visible.